# Android create reusable button template

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-custom-view

Need to create a reusable button component in Android.

Application has a common button style. This common button style is maintained everywhere.
The button consists of few properties and they are dynamic for each button.

Eg:- For login button, the button text will be login and icon can be different. For submit button, button title will be submit and the icon will be a different one(button UI should be same)

I know from the button with a drawable background can create a basic button UI. But in this case button UI is bit complex and button properties should be dynamically changeable and accessible via xml code.
I have attached a sample button design and some of the button properties that should be changed dynamically.
How can I create reusable button template?

- Short test(user01)
- Image
- Button Title
- button background color
- Short area color etc

[image]

Comment: Subclass Button and use your subclass. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components